stream select taking too long
I have to final tables, table_1 and table_2, first one with 6.4B rows and second one with 6.3B rows. None of this tables are clustered
On top of this tables, each one have a stream, standard ones, stream_1 and stream_2 respectively.
When i query those streams, grouping by a date column, first one response in seconds,
query profile like this,

Indicating that catch 8 million new rows approx.
But when i query second one, takes over an hour and the query profile indicates this:


Indicating that makes like two table scans and then joining them, the result are like 12 million rows, not a big difference with the first one, i don't get it.
Any thoughts on why is doing this?
Stream definitions:
CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS db.schema.STREAM_1 
ON TABLE db.schema.table_1;

CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS db.schema.STREAM_2 
ON TABLE db.schema.table_2;

query stream:
select date_column::date,count(1) 
from db.schema.stream_1 
group by date_column::date 
order by date_column::date desc;

select date_column,count(1) 
from db.schema.stream_2 
group by date_column 
order by date_column desc;


Please update your question with the actual queries you are running as well as both stream definitions. Your second query has 6 billion records in the source, compared to 9 million for the first query - that’s probably got something to do with the performance difference

@NickW edited, as i mentioned above, i'm query the streams, first stream only made cdc for almost 9million rows and ended up in like miliseconds, but for second streams returns 12million but after almost 1 hr and 15 minutes and the query profiles are totally different

The first query only starts with 9 million records; the second query starts with 6 billion records and only gets filtered down to 6 million later - so it’s obvious that the second one will take longer to run. I don’t know why the second one has a different query profile but I would guess that the first query is on a stream that has never been consumed so it just gives you all records; the second query is a delta of the underlying table and so needs to join to itself to generate the complete delta dataset

Can you also provide how the underlying tables are being refreshed?  It looks like table_2 might be getting completely refreshed?

@MikeWalton hi, could it be that if table_2 was recreated (create or replace) and the stream was recreated alse, so after this, the stream no only make cdc of the 12 millions rows that returned but could need to query all the table? idk

If the table and stream were both recreated, then the stream should be empty.  If the table only was replaced, I think the stream is "broken" because the underlying object is actually gone.  One way to confirm the actual size of the stream would be to run a count on it.

The other behavioral things that I was going to suggest, as well, is that a stream that is append-only behaves different from one that isn't.  Your DDL for your streams doesn't make a note of that, though.  However, running a SHOW STREAMS might confirm.

@MikeWalton hi Mike i just saw the response, the streams are standard ones, i keep having the same issue, a group by over this streams that usually have like something between 7 and 10 millions rows, is taking too long to response over a group by select.. It's weird and is consuming too much credits

@NickW yes that could be but i have other streams that i have been using over a year now, this streams receive 8 million rows or so every day and when i use the data from this streams to do a merge is not taking more than 10-15min, maybe is because i insert the data from the stream into a temporary table and then query this temp table, maybe i should do the same here, no the group by over the stream but first create a temp table and then de group by over this one
